# Is it possible to train for precision in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

Can I train a binary classifier in Tensorflow to maximize precision?

Comment: Please elaborate. What kind of precision do you mean? Precision of training data or test data?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I meant for the training data, and actually think I found the answer at:https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits

Comment: However, any advice on getting a better true positive rate in the test set is also appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. Precision is not useful in a loss function. It does provide a clear signal to choose model parameters.

Precision can be used as an evaluation metric. In particular, precision on a hold-out dataset (e.g., validation dataset) can be used to pick hyperparameters.